# How can a human blacksmith expert and a merchant goblin open a forge?

Tags: character-creation, background, symbaroum

I'm actually thinking about a backstory that links both characters for *Symbaroum*.

In this universe, where elves, trolls, dwarves and goblins exist, it is common for humans to be racist towards other races. Goblins are seen as unstable and simplistic creatures; of course, not all of them are like that.

As for my characters, the human is a master blacksmith who owns the forge but lacks any social skills. He likes to hoard knowledge, and even if he has the look of a warrior, he is actually a mage-type character. Meanwhile, the goblin is a tactician who has incredible social skills, can rally his allies towards a common goal, and he is also a good liar.

So my question is, what is the relationship between the goblin and the blacksmith in order to make them collaborate and open a forge together?

Comment: Hi, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how the site works and visit the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more information. Unfortunately, it seems as though you're asking for ideas for your character's backstory, and RPG.SE is more of a Q&A site where opinions don't really work that well. Your question might be better suited to a forum, of which we have made [a list of recommendations](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/35259). If you have any questions about [tag:symbaroum] that are less opinion based, feel free to ask them here! Happy gaming!